# stopping an AVAudioPlayer

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, avaudioplayer

here is my code

```
 NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"95" ofType:@"wav"];

NSError *activationError = nil;
NSError *audioPlayerInitError = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error:&activationError];

NSURL *newURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
musicPlayer1 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:newURL error:&audioPlayerInitError];

if (musicPlayer1) {
    [musicPlayer1 stop];
    [musicPlayer1 release];
    musicPlayer1 = nil;
}
else {

    [musicPlayer1 prepareToPlay];
    [musicPlayer1 setVolume:.8];
    [musicPlayer1 setNumberOfLoops:-1]; // -1 means play indefintely
    [musicPlayer1 setDelegate: self];
    [musicPlayer1 play];
}
```

}

I am rying to start and stop the AVAudioPlay with the same button (musicPlayer1 is in the header). Now when i touch the button it does not play anything. Help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating a new instance of `AVAudioPlayer` each time. You need to hold onto the reference to the object somewhere, and refer back to that. Add a field to your view controller class:

```
@private AVAudioPlayer *currentAudio;
```

And then in this method, make the following changes:

```
if (currentAudio) {
    [currentAudio stop];
    [currentAudio release];
    currentAudio = nil;
} else {
    // what you already have goes here
}
```

Comment: im assuming u r declaring @private in the header

Comment: also, i have 8 more of these so should i implement 8 more AVAudioPlayers or would it be more efficient to use the same one for all 9

Comment: The amount of memory used by 9 pointers is trivial, so it doesn't matter how many fields in a class you have. However, if you are attempting to run 9 `AVAudioPlayer` instances at a time, each one should be managed separately.

Comment: When i put this in my header i get "expected identifier or "(" before 'private'

Comment: You have to put it in an Objective-C class' member section. In between `{` and `}` after `@interface SomethingOrOther`. ;)

Comment: ah yes wow my fault haha. however the only problem when i do this is that now wen i click a button it doesnt play anything

Comment: Amend your question to show the entire method. I can't psychically debug your problems.

Comment: i understand that but this didn't fix the problem. The only difference bwtween my current code and my previous is i put in your if statement, added the field in my header, and took out the pointer (AVAudioPlayer *musicPlayer, now it just says musicPlayer)

Comment: You have to put the `[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] init...` line in the second branch. Otherwise it gets executed every time, and then you're back to square one.